# Interview question regarding scalability of the application

Tags: interviewing

I have had two different interviewers, in two different occasions, asking me one similar question.

**What is the number of end users of the application that I am currently working on?**

I gave a rough figure to which the panel mocked and said it is very small.

In one case, it was ~ 100 to 200. But, that amount of data that was generated was huge and this has to run 24x7, 365 days. It could have been scaled up later but I was not part of it. Till the time I was involved in it, I was part of the coding team.

I do understand that different applications cater to different users and the numbers vary significantly based on the domain and also on the requirement. I could have been rejected based on this alone or many other factors.

I guess their main intention was to see if I can be a part of applications with bigger user counts. However, I do not have experience working on applications with a large number of users.

**My question is, how should I answer questions like this - where my experience doesn't match what they're looking for - in a way that minimizes the negative effect on me?

Comment: I don't understand the interview question. *What* application? Theirs? The one your wrote at the last company?

Comment: @nvoigt yes, the applications that I am working at present and the previous ones too.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The application had already gone live to production and was in maintenance/upgrade phase. I was speaking to my other friends and this seems to be a very common question here.

Comment: @nvoigt I have edited my question. Would be glad to add more details as needed.

Comment: "a rough figure to which the panel mocked and said it is very less." - Do you mean they mocked it and said the figure was too low? E.g. "About 100 to 200 people use the app." "Bah! So few? Are you even trying?"

Comment: @Brandin "Bah! So few? Are you even trying?" so few part is yes. But, that is what the application was developed for, 100-200 users. The scope of that application is limited.

Comment: @WonderWoman You could have just responded that way, e.g. "this app was only meant for very specific users, not a broad user base." or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should answer it honestly and with thinking. This is a typical question where they want to test your ability to separate very different aspects of professional SW development processes. The number of users has a different impact than the data size.

Data size is usually a pure infrastructure and mathematical/computational problem, while number of users has impact on your development cycles, required stability of data format, software quality, release planning, and testing.

A typical though process which I would expect of an experienced professional SW developer is e.g. the tradeoff between a more stable and/or well supported, but less efficient solution and a cutting-edge technology, where your team has potentially to give support to every end-user.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with being honest like @Sascha mentioned. Let me provide a parallel example. I work as a cybersecurity professional - security analyst and former auditor. In much there is a tradeoff between well supported software vs efficient software, there is a tradeoff between security vs end user acceptance / friendness.

I have frequently encountered questions in past interviews about how I would handle end user complaints / support their needs while not compromising security of the systems or compromise to the minimum degree required to satisfy end users, assuming end user requests were reasonable.

To draw a parallel, about how reducing the security of a system can be mitigated as a negative, I answered that supporting end users is important, and that no matter how secure the system is, if end users cannot use it, **then security is irrelevant.** In your situation, if the system cannot be easily scaled to support the growing end user base, then if even the system can easily handle large amounts of data, **that capability is reduced due to limited numbers of end users being able to use such functionality simultaneously.**

Summary: Think about how to balance opposing needs and answer accordingly.